# dynamic height with animation and all elements vertical align middle

Tags: jquery, html, css

i have radio buttons that use global classes. I want as little code as possible to be able to reuse the elements... There are several ways to display the radio buttons. One label with info that appears when clicked, and one label with a lot of text.

If there is a lot of text I have the problem that it merges into the radio button.

Does anyone have an idea how I can use the code for both cases? 
The elements should always be Vertical-Align middle.

Example and Bug here:

```js
var checkbox = $('.js-inputround');

(function($) {
  $(document).ready(function() {


    checkbox.each(function() {
      if ($(this).prop('checked')) {
        $(this).parent('.input-round__option').addClass('js-check-svg');
        $(this).parent('.js-show-info').addClass('js-show');
      }
    });


    //show small info,toggle active icon
    checkbox.change(function() {
      if (checkbox.length) {
        if (checkbox.is(":checked")) {
          roundInputShowElements($(this));

        } else {
          roundInputHideElements($(this));
        }
      }


    });

  });

  $(window).on('pageshow', function() {
    checkbox.each(function() {
      if ($(this).prop('checked')) {
        $(this).parent('.input-round__option').addClass('js-check-svg');
        $(this).parent('.js-show-info').addClass('js-show');
      }
    });
  });


})(jQuery);


function roundInputShowElements(element) {
  element.parent('.js-show-info').addClass('js-show');
  element.parent('.input-round__option').addClass('js-check-svg');
}


function roundInputHideElements(element) {
  element.parent('.js-show-info').removeClass("js-show");
  element.parent('.input-round__option').removeClass('js-check-svg');
}
```

```css
.input-round__container {
  min-height: 55px;
}

.input-round__option {
  display: block;
  vertical-align: middle;
  position: relative;
  height: 100%;
}

.input-round__input {
  -webkit-appearance: none;
  -moz-appearance: none;
  appearance: none;
  cursor: pointer;
  display: inline-block;
  outline: none;
  vertical-align: middle;
  margin: 0;
}

.icon {
  fill: currentColor;
  width: 25px;
  height: 25px;
  display: inline-block;
  vertical-align: middle;
  -webkit-user-select: none;
  -moz-user-select: none;
  -ms-user-select: none;
  user-select: none;
}

.input-round__icon {
  position: absolute;
  left: 0;
  top: 50%;
  transform: translateY(-50%);
  margin: 0;
  color: #CB4C40;
}

.js-check-svg .input-round__icon--active {
  opacity: 1;
  transition: all 0.1s;
}

.icon {
  fill: currentColor;
  width: 25px;
  height: 25px;
  display: inline-block;
  vertical-align: middle;
  user-select: none;
}

.input-round__icon--active {
  opacity: 0;
  transition: all 0.1s;
}

.input-round__option input {
  opacity: 0;
  margin: 0;
}

.input-round__text {
  display: inline-block;
  top: 50%;
  position: relative;
  -webkit-transform: translateY(-50%);
  transform: translateY(-50%);
  padding-left: 10px;
}

.js-check-svg .input-round__label {
  font-weight: 500;
  font-size: 16px;
  line-height: 20px;
  color: #46474a;
  transition: all 0.1s;
}

.input-round__option.js-show .input-round__info {
  display: block;
  opacity: 1;
  height: 18px;
}

.input-round__info {
  height: 0;
  opacity: 0;
  -webkit-transition: all 0.3s;
  transition: all 0.3s;
  display: block;
  font-weight: 400;
  color: #848e8e;
  font-size: 14px;
  line-height: 18px;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="input-round__container">
<label class="input-round__option js-show-info js-show js-check-svg" data-qa="label">


    <div class="input-round__input">

        <svg class="icon icon--biggest input-round__icon" id=":option_no_35" viewBox="0 0 35 35" width="100%"
             height="100%"><title id=":option-title">option</title>
            <path d="M17.5,35 C7.83501688,35 0,27.1649831 0,17.5 C0,7.83501688 7.83501688,0 17.5,0 C27.1649831,0 35,7.83501688 35,17.5 C35,27.1649831 27.1649831,35 17.5,35 Z M17.5,33.90625 C26.5609217,33.90625 33.90625,26.5609217 33.90625,17.5 C33.90625,8.43907832 26.5609217,1.09375 17.5,1.09375 C8.43907832,1.09375 1.09375,8.43907832 1.09375,17.5 C1.09375,26.5609217 8.43907832,33.90625 17.5,33.90625 Z"
                  id="path-1"></path>
        </svg>


        <svg class="icon icon--biggest input-round__icon input-round__icon--active" id=":checkbox-yes_35"
             viewBox="0 0 35 35" width="100%" height="100%"><title id=":checkbox-yes-title">checkbox-yes</title>
            <path d="M17.5,35 C7.83501688,35 0,27.1649831 0,17.5 C0,7.83501688 7.83501688,0 17.5,0 C27.1649831,0 35,7.83501688 35,17.5 C35,27.1649831 27.1649831,35 17.5,35 Z M17.5,33.90625 C26.5609217,33.90625 33.90625,26.5609217 33.90625,17.5 C33.90625,8.43907832 26.5609217,1.09375 17.5,1.09375 C8.43907832,1.09375 1.09375,8.43907832 1.09375,17.5 C1.09375,26.5609217 8.43907832,33.90625 17.5,33.90625 Z M25.8920268,12.6750186 C26.2749325,13.0132068 26.2749325,13.5666056 25.8938589,13.9031757 L25.1921705,14.5229176 L17.2189383,21.5585261 L16.5282424,22.1717955 C16.3340414,22.3416987 16.0812137,22.4306956 15.826554,22.4306956 C15.5755584,22.4306956 15.3245628,22.3416987 15.1321939,22.1717955 L14.441498,21.5585261 L10.4512177,18.0374856 C10.0646479,17.6960612 10.0646479,17.1458986 10.4512177,16.8044742 C10.6454187,16.634571 10.8982464,16.5488104 11.1492419,16.5488104 C11.4002375,16.5488104 11.6530652,16.634571 11.843602,16.8044742 L15.826554,20.3287509 L24.4959783,12.6750186 C24.6901793,12.5051155 24.9393428,12.4225911 25.1903384,12.4193548 L25.1940026,12.4193548 C25.4449982,12.4193548 25.6996579,12.5051155 25.8920268,12.6750186 Z"
                  id="path-1"></path>
        </svg>


    </div>

    <input class="js-inputround " type="checkbox" id="one" >


    <div class="input-round__text">
        <span class="input-round__label ">Label</span>
        <span class="input-round__info ">small information</span>
    </div>
</label>
</div>


<div class="input-round__container">
<label class="input-round__option " data-qa="label">


    <div class="input-round__input">

        <svg class="icon icon--biggest input-round__icon" id=":option_no_35" viewBox="0 0 35 35" width="100%"
             height="100%"><title id=":option-title">option</title>
            <path d="M17.5,35 C7.83501688,35 0,27.1649831 0,17.5 C0,7.83501688 7.83501688,0 17.5,0 C27.1649831,0 35,7.83501688 35,17.5 C35,27.1649831 27.1649831,35 17.5,35 Z M17.5,33.90625 C26.5609217,33.90625 33.90625,26.5609217 33.90625,17.5 C33.90625,8.43907832 26.5609217,1.09375 17.5,1.09375 C8.43907832,1.09375 1.09375,8.43907832 1.09375,17.5 C1.09375,26.5609217 8.43907832,33.90625 17.5,33.90625 Z"
                  id="path-1"></path>
        </svg>


        <svg class="icon icon--biggest input-round__icon input-round__icon--active" id=":checkbox-yes_35"
             viewBox="0 0 35 35" width="100%" height="100%"><title id=":checkbox-yes-title">checkbox-yes</title>
            <path d="M17.5,35 C7.83501688,35 0,27.1649831 0,17.5 C0,7.83501688 7.83501688,0 17.5,0 C27.1649831,0 35,7.83501688 35,17.5 C35,27.1649831 27.1649831,35 17.5,35 Z M17.5,33.90625 C26.5609217,33.90625 33.90625,26.5609217 33.90625,17.5 C33.90625,8.43907832 26.5609217,1.09375 17.5,1.09375 C8.43907832,1.09375 1.09375,8.43907832 1.09375,17.5 C1.09375,26.5609217 8.43907832,33.90625 17.5,33.90625 Z M25.8920268,12.6750186 C26.2749325,13.0132068 26.2749325,13.5666056 25.8938589,13.9031757 L25.1921705,14.5229176 L17.2189383,21.5585261 L16.5282424,22.1717955 C16.3340414,22.3416987 16.0812137,22.4306956 15.826554,22.4306956 C15.5755584,22.4306956 15.3245628,22.3416987 15.1321939,22.1717955 L14.441498,21.5585261 L10.4512177,18.0374856 C10.0646479,17.6960612 10.0646479,17.1458986 10.4512177,16.8044742 C10.6454187,16.634571 10.8982464,16.5488104 11.1492419,16.5488104 C11.4002375,16.5488104 11.6530652,16.634571 11.843602,16.8044742 L15.826554,20.3287509 L24.4959783,12.6750186 C24.6901793,12.5051155 24.9393428,12.4225911 25.1903384,12.4193548 L25.1940026,12.4193548 C25.4449982,12.4193548 25.6996579,12.5051155 25.8920268,12.6750186 Z"
                  id="path-1"></path>
        </svg>

    </div>

    <input class="js-inputround " type="checkbox" required="" id="two" name="" value="1">


    <div class="input-round__text">
        <span class="input-round__label label--required">Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consetetur sadipscing elitr, sed diam nonumy eirmod tempor invidunt ut labore et dolore magna aliquyam erat, sed diam voluptua. At vero eos et accusam et justo duo dolores et ea rebum</span>
        <span class="input-round__info "></span>
    </div>
</label>
</div>
```

Comment: Code relevant to your question belongs directly into your question (in text form and properly formatted), not just dumped on an external site.

Comment: @04FS okei i changed it

Comment: Although being inline-block, your `.input-round__text` can still take the full width, and then it moves to the next line. One way to prevent that would to give it a max-width.

Answer (score 1):

Just add width: calc(100% - 40px);

```
.input-round__text {
      display: inline-block;
      top: 50%;
      position: relative;
      -webkit-transform: translateY(-50%);
      transform: translateY(-50%);
      padding-left: 10px;
width: calc(100% - 40px);
    }
```

```js
var checkbox = $('.js-inputround');

(function($) {
  $(document).ready(function() {


    checkbox.each(function() {
      if ($(this).prop('checked')) {
        $(this).parent('.input-round__option').addClass('js-check-svg');
        $(this).parent('.js-show-info').addClass('js-show');
      }
    });


    //show small info,toggle active icon
    checkbox.change(function() {
      if (checkbox.length) {
        if (checkbox.is(":checked")) {
          roundInputShowElements($(this));

        } else {
          roundInputHideElements($(this));
        }
      }


    });

  });

  $(window).on('pageshow', function() {
    checkbox.each(function() {
      if ($(this).prop('checked')) {
        $(this).parent('.input-round__option').addClass('js-check-svg');
        $(this).parent('.js-show-info').addClass('js-show');
      }
    });
  });


})(jQuery);


function roundInputShowElements(element) {
  element.parent('.js-show-info').addClass('js-show');
  element.parent('.input-round__option').addClass('js-check-svg');
}


function roundInputHideElements(element) {
  element.parent('.js-show-info').removeClass("js-show");
  element.parent('.input-round__option').removeClass('js-check-svg');
}
```

```css
.input-round__container {
  height: 55px;
}

.input-round__option {
  display: block;
  vertical-align: middle;
  position: relative;
  height: 100%;
}

.input-round__input {
  -webkit-appearance: none;
  -moz-appearance: none;
  appearance: none;
  cursor: pointer;
  display: inline-block;
  outline: none;
  vertical-align: middle;
  margin: 0;
}

.icon {
  fill: currentColor;
  width: 25px;
  height: 25px;
  display: inline-block;
  vertical-align: middle;
  -webkit-user-select: none;
  -moz-user-select: none;
  -ms-user-select: none;
  user-select: none;
}

.input-round__icon {
  position: absolute;
  left: 0;
  top: 50%;
  transform: translateY(-50%);
  margin: 0;
  color: #CB4C40;
}

.js-check-svg .input-round__icon--active {
  opacity: 1;
  transition: all 0.1s;
}

.icon {
  fill: currentColor;
  width: 25px;
  height: 25px;
  display: inline-block;
  vertical-align: middle;
  user-select: none;
}

.input-round__icon--active {
  opacity: 0;
  transition: all 0.1s;
}

.input-round__option input {
  opacity: 0;
  margin: 0;
}

.input-round__text {
  display: inline-block;
  top: 50%;
  position: relative;
  -webkit-transform: translateY(-50%);
  transform: translateY(-50%);
  padding-left: 10px;
width: calc(100% - 40px);
}

.js-check-svg .input-round__label {
  font-weight: 500;
  font-size: 16px;
  line-height: 20px;
  color: #46474a;
  transition: all 0.1s;
}

.input-round__option.js-show .input-round__info {
  display: block;
  opacity: 1;
  height: 18px;
}

.input-round__info {
  height: 0;
  opacity: 0;
  -webkit-transition: all 0.3s;
  transition: all 0.3s;
  display: block;
  font-weight: 400;
  color: #848e8e;
  font-size: 14px;
  line-height: 18px;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="input-round__container">
<label class="input-round__option js-show-info js-show js-check-svg" data-qa="label">


    <div class="input-round__input">

        <svg class="icon icon--biggest input-round__icon" id=":option_no_35" viewBox="0 0 35 35" width="100%"
             height="100%"><title id=":option-title">option</title>
            <path d="M17.5,35 C7.83501688,35 0,27.1649831 0,17.5 C0,7.83501688 7.83501688,0 17.5,0 C27.1649831,0 35,7.83501688 35,17.5 C35,27.1649831 27.1649831,35 17.5,35 Z M17.5,33.90625 C26.5609217,33.90625 33.90625,26.5609217 33.90625,17.5 C33.90625,8.43907832 26.5609217,1.09375 17.5,1.09375 C8.43907832,1.09375 1.09375,8.43907832 1.09375,17.5 C1.09375,26.5609217 8.43907832,33.90625 17.5,33.90625 Z"
                  id="path-1"></path>
        </svg>


        <svg class="icon icon--biggest input-round__icon input-round__icon--active" id=":checkbox-yes_35"
             viewBox="0 0 35 35" width="100%" height="100%"><title id=":checkbox-yes-title">checkbox-yes</title>
            <path d="M17.5,35 C7.83501688,35 0,27.1649831 0,17.5 C0,7.83501688 7.83501688,0 17.5,0 C27.1649831,0 35,7.83501688 35,17.5 C35,27.1649831 27.1649831,35 17.5,35 Z M17.5,33.90625 C26.5609217,33.90625 33.90625,26.5609217 33.90625,17.5 C33.90625,8.43907832 26.5609217,1.09375 17.5,1.09375 C8.43907832,1.09375 1.09375,8.43907832 1.09375,17.5 C1.09375,26.5609217 8.43907832,33.90625 17.5,33.90625 Z M25.8920268,12.6750186 C26.2749325,13.0132068 26.2749325,13.5666056 25.8938589,13.9031757 L25.1921705,14.5229176 L17.2189383,21.5585261 L16.5282424,22.1717955 C16.3340414,22.3416987 16.0812137,22.4306956 15.826554,22.4306956 C15.5755584,22.4306956 15.3245628,22.3416987 15.1321939,22.1717955 L14.441498,21.5585261 L10.4512177,18.0374856 C10.0646479,17.6960612 10.0646479,17.1458986 10.4512177,16.8044742 C10.6454187,16.634571 10.8982464,16.5488104 11.1492419,16.5488104 C11.4002375,16.5488104 11.6530652,16.634571 11.843602,16.8044742 L15.826554,20.3287509 L24.4959783,12.6750186 C24.6901793,12.5051155 24.9393428,12.4225911 25.1903384,12.4193548 L25.1940026,12.4193548 C25.4449982,12.4193548 25.6996579,12.5051155 25.8920268,12.6750186 Z"
                  id="path-1"></path>
        </svg>


    </div>

    <input class="js-inputround " type="checkbox" id="one" >


    <div class="input-round__text">
        <span class="input-round__label ">Label</span>
        <span class="input-round__info ">small information</span>
    </div>
</label>
</div>


<div class="input-round__container">
<label class="input-round__option " data-qa="label">


    <div class="input-round__input">

        <svg class="icon icon--biggest input-round__icon" id=":option_no_35" viewBox="0 0 35 35" width="100%"
             height="100%"><title id=":option-title">option</title>
            <path d="M17.5,35 C7.83501688,35 0,27.1649831 0,17.5 C0,7.83501688 7.83501688,0 17.5,0 C27.1649831,0 35,7.83501688 35,17.5 C35,27.1649831 27.1649831,35 17.5,35 Z M17.5,33.90625 C26.5609217,33.90625 33.90625,26.5609217 33.90625,17.5 C33.90625,8.43907832 26.5609217,1.09375 17.5,1.09375 C8.43907832,1.09375 1.09375,8.43907832 1.09375,17.5 C1.09375,26.5609217 8.43907832,33.90625 17.5,33.90625 Z"
                  id="path-1"></path>
        </svg>


        <svg class="icon icon--biggest input-round__icon input-round__icon--active" id=":checkbox-yes_35"
             viewBox="0 0 35 35" width="100%" height="100%"><title id=":checkbox-yes-title">checkbox-yes</title>
            <path d="M17.5,35 C7.83501688,35 0,27.1649831 0,17.5 C0,7.83501688 7.83501688,0 17.5,0 C27.1649831,0 35,7.83501688 35,17.5 C35,27.1649831 27.1649831,35 17.5,35 Z M17.5,33.90625 C26.5609217,33.90625 33.90625,26.5609217 33.90625,17.5 C33.90625,8.43907832 26.5609217,1.09375 17.5,1.09375 C8.43907832,1.09375 1.09375,8.43907832 1.09375,17.5 C1.09375,26.5609217 8.43907832,33.90625 17.5,33.90625 Z M25.8920268,12.6750186 C26.2749325,13.0132068 26.2749325,13.5666056 25.8938589,13.9031757 L25.1921705,14.5229176 L17.2189383,21.5585261 L16.5282424,22.1717955 C16.3340414,22.3416987 16.0812137,22.4306956 15.826554,22.4306956 C15.5755584,22.4306956 15.3245628,22.3416987 15.1321939,22.1717955 L14.441498,21.5585261 L10.4512177,18.0374856 C10.0646479,17.6960612 10.0646479,17.1458986 10.4512177,16.8044742 C10.6454187,16.634571 10.8982464,16.5488104 11.1492419,16.5488104 C11.4002375,16.5488104 11.6530652,16.634571 11.843602,16.8044742 L15.826554,20.3287509 L24.4959783,12.6750186 C24.6901793,12.5051155 24.9393428,12.4225911 25.1903384,12.4193548 L25.1940026,12.4193548 C25.4449982,12.4193548 25.6996579,12.5051155 25.8920268,12.6750186 Z"
                  id="path-1"></path>
        </svg>

    </div>

    <input class="js-inputround " type="checkbox" required="" id="two" name="" value="1">


    <div class="input-round__text">
        <span class="input-round__label label--required">Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consetetur sadipscing elitr, sed diam nonumy eirmod tempor invidunt ut labore et dolore magna aliquyam erat, sed diam voluptua. At vero eos et accusam et justo duo dolores et ea rebum</span>
        <span class="input-round__info "></span>
    </div>
</label>
</div>
```

Comment: that works, thanks, have you an idea for the problem with the min-height of the parent?

Comment: can you explain in brief?

Comment: fixed it by myself, add to .input-round__text :   vertical-align: middle;
    display: inline-block;